# Determine next business day

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code to determine the next market day( which comes up every 4days). Am able to print a list of market days from one market date. If I run the code on a day isn't market day, the list will not be correct because it will only add 4 days. but I need the code to print just the next market day. For instance, the last market day was 29/5/17, the next should be 2/6/17.
Do I need to create a file containing the list of dates and compare?

```
 import datetime
 today = datetime.date.today()
 year = int(input('Enter a year: '))
 month = int(input('Enter a month: '))
 day = int(input('Enter a day: '))
 date2 = datetime.date(year, month, day)
 mday = datetime.timedelta(days=4)
 print('Market days till ',date2)

 while today <= date2:
    mtoday = (today.strftime('\nNext Market day: %A, %B %d, %Y'))
    print (mtoday)
    today = today + mday
```

Comment: So far, you have 4 answers, you really should make the effort to pick one of them as "correct", and/or pick one or more as "useful".

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple solution to this but everyone involving changing your input parameters(If that is acceptable).

First Solution.
Take the input as Last Market Day.
Then your solution works fine

Second Solution.
Take the date time along with day_delta_since_last_market_day

you can take this delta and add it with the "datetime" before adding 4 days.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import datetime
 today = datetime.date.today()
 date2 = datetime.date(2016, 5, 26) #a reference of a passed market day
 mday = datetime.timedelta(days=4)
 a=date2
 while a<today:
    a=a+mday
 print a
```

If the market day of reference was (2016, 5, 26) then the next market day after today will be :

```
>>> print a
2017-06-01
```

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion works but i need it to print just the next market day if possible

Comment: the next day after today ? or the next day after one reference date ?

Comment: if `print a` is out of the while loop (be careful with identation) it will print the next day of market after today with the given reference.

Comment: Wow! It works Perfectly. My indentation was actually wrong. Thanks Dadep

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the number of days to the next market day and the date of the next market day, this should do the trick:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

first_market_day = date(year=2017, month=5, day=29)
market_day_period = timedelta(days=4)

def is_market_day(value):
    if value >= first_market_day:
        if (value-first_market_day).days % market_day_period.days == 0:
            return True
    return False

def next_market_day(value):
    if value >= first_market_day:
        days_past_last = timedelta(days=(value-first_market_day).days % market_day_period.days)
        return value + timedelta(days=4) - days_past_last
    else:
        return first_market_day
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference market day, doesn't matter which one, just a day that you knew a market occurred on, after that it's just a matter of calculation.

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
year = int(input('Enter a year: '))
month = int(input('Enter a month: '))
day = int(input('Enter a day: '))
last_market = str(input('Enter date of last known market(yyyymmdd): '))
lm = datetime.date(int(last_market[:4]),int(last_market[4:6]),int(last_market[6:]))
date2 = datetime.date(year, month, day)
mday = datetime.timedelta(days=4)
print('Market days till ',date2.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
while lm <= today:
    lm = lm + mday
today = lm
while today <= date2:
    mtoday = (today.strftime('\nNext Market day: %A, %B %d, %Y'))
    print (mtoday)
    today = today + mday
```